# C#: Explicitly specifying the interface in an implementation's method

Tags: c#, interface, access-modifiers

Why is it that when implementing an interface, if I make the method public I do not have to explicitly specify the interface, but if I make it private I have to...like such (*`GetQueryString` is a method from IBar*):

```
public class Foo : IBar
{
    //This doesn't compile
    string GetQueryString() 
    {
        ///...
    }

    //But this does:
    string IBar.GetQueryString() 
    {
        ///...
    }
}
```

So why do you have to specify the interface explicitly when the method is made private, but not when the method is public ?

Comment: When you say doesn't work do you mean - does not compile or does not run as expected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Explicit interface implementation is a sort of half-way house between public and private: it's public if you're using an interface-typed reference to get at it, but that's the *only* way of accessing it (even in the same class).

If you're using implicit interface implementation you need to specify it as public because it *is* a public method you're overriding by virtue of it being in the interface. In other words, the valid code is:

```
public class Foo : IBar
{
    // Implicit implementation
    public string GetQueryString() 
    {
        ///...
    }

    // Explicit implementation - no access modifier is allowed
    string IBar.GetQueryString() 
    {
        ///...
    }
}
```

Personally I rarely use explicit interface implementation unless it's required for things like `IEnumerable<T>` which has different signatures for `GetEnumerator` based on whether it's the generic or non-generic interface:

```
public class Foo : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        ...
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator(); // Call to the generic version
    }
}
```

Here you *have* to use explicit interface implementation to avoid trying to overload based on return type.

Comment: Jon, I made amendments to my code in the post, because I did a mistake earlier on in mapping out exactly my code.